# Passportjs Slack - Scope errors

Tags: passport.js, slack, slack-api

I am using `passport-slack` to authenticate with Slack but I keep stumbling on missing scope issues.

In the scope for passport, I have asked for the `identity.basic` permission but I keep getting the below error from Slack API.

What am I doing wrong?

```
passport.use('Slack', new SlackStrategy({
        clientID         : secret.slack.id,
        clientSecret     : secret.slack.secret,
        skipUserProfile  : false,
        callbackURL      : '/sessions/slack/callback',
        // scope            : ['channels:read', 'chat:write:bot', 'identity.basic'],
        scope            : ['identity.basic', 'identity.email', 'identity.avatar', 'identity.team', 'channels:read', 'chat:write:bot'],
        passReqToCallback: true
    }, (req, accessToken, scopes, profile, done) => {

        // Code to process the response
    })

)
```

```
{
    "ok":false,
    "error":"missing_scope",
    "needed":"identity.basic",
    "provided":"identify,incoming-webhook,channels:read,chat:write:bot"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solved -**

I was using Slack to publish messages on the channels. Scope needed for these permissions are -

`channels:read, chat:write:bot`

For the above purpose, one should use the `add to slack` button which gives me the workspace's token to publish on channels thus eliminating the need for SlackStrategy altogether.

Initially, I used the SlackStrategy which was incorrect because that would only be used to `Login with Slack`, something I didn't need.

So, I have now removed SlackStrategy since all I need is permission to publish on Slack and not authenticate users via Slack.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your passport use, please try and **remove the first parameter of the method** such as:

```
passport.use(new SlackStrategy({
    clientID         : secret.slack.id,
    clientSecret     : secret.slack.secret,
    skipUserProfile  : false,
    callbackURL      : '/sessions/slack/callback',
    // scope            : ['channels:read', 'chat:write:bot', 'identity.basic'],
    scope            : ['identity.basic', 'identity.email', 'identity.avatar', 'identity.team', 'channels:read', 'chat:write:bot'],
    passReqToCallback: true
    }, (req, accessToken, scopes, profile, done) => {

    // Code to process the response
    })
)
```

Check here for working example: https://github.com/mjpearson/passport-slack#configure-strategy

Comment: What was the typo?

Comment: The first argument of the use() method is not needed!

Comment: The first argument is used to name the scope. I agree it's not needed but there are cases when you need to have multiple strategies and it comes in handy.

Comment: So it still does not work? No scopes are being sent?

Comment: I did a gore mistake of mixing `Add to Slack` with `Login via Slack`. This caused the confusion. Thanks for taking a look.